# What causes NAS timeouts

Tags: windows

What causes my NAS to timeout when copying a lot of files?

It will just randomly time out and when you open up my computer you just see the green status bar going across and things just go slow and lag.

I am on Windows 7

The drives are also brand new along with all the hardware. I have network discovery off as well

This is also in a Hyper-V.

I've noticed I get the error "The specified network name is no longer available."

Possible fix to this:

Use the IP and skip/bypass relying on the WINS/DNS/NAME for resolving.

Comment: "when copying a LOT of files"? that could be for minutes or for the day?  Then you indicate "openeing up the computer"  which suggests that the thing might be going into sleep or standby.  the win7 system is still stupid enough to standby completly during the most vigorus disk activity, unless it is told not to.

Answer (score 0):

We definitely need more information.

My hunch though is it's probably the disks in the NAS not keeping up due to a faulty RAID array because of a bad disk. That can create quite a bit of overhead.

Comment: What kind of information is needed? As far as the RAID goes in the NAS, they are just 2x4TB drives working as one.

Comment: Just drives :-)  more information might include the type of NAS, the actual drives model, or if they are greens or not at least.